# Designing keyboard on J2ME color mobile

Tags: java-me, midp, cldc, lcdui

I want to create a J2ME application for writing SMS faster using QWERTY button on a simple **non-qwerty** phone.  So the application will show all these buttons which user can use [image]

I've knowledge on Java and have developed simple calculator too but cant design it in NetBeans.

So looking for help [only to design the interface,]

This app will run on a simple phone with [1-abc] [2-def] keypad

Comment: do you target your app for a touch screen device (these typically have virtual keyboard)? or for a device with a [telephone keypad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad)?

Comment: this app will run on a simple phone with [1-abc] [2-def] device

Comment: I see - what do you mean when you note "can't design it in NetBeans"? For your calculator, did you use some sort of wizard in IDE or did you manually programmed Canvas drawing and handling events? or something else?

Comment: I tried to design it using the latest NetBeans

Comment: I see. could you show an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) version of code you have for it so far? especially - what `import` statements you use?

Comment: import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically your idea looks doable - at least if device screen is large enough to handle 4 rows of your pseudo-buttons plus at least one row for SMS text.

And it doesn't even look very difficult - in this sense your idea looks good to me. In MIDP lcdui package, classes `Canvas`, `Graphics` and `Font` seem to have all the stuff one would need to do that.

- Yeah that would make a good exercise in mobile UI. On the other hand, I wouldn't bet on such a design being more convenient for users compared to say, plain [lcdui TextBox](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextBox.html) which simply utilizes platform-specific key entries whatever they are.
   
  Just think of it... On smaller screen devices, TextBox will give users much larger area to view text - just because your design will occupy quite a lot of screen space with the "keypad". On large screen devices, your chances are even worse because these tend to have virtual or even real qwerty and this one will most likely be utilized by TextBox which will be as good if not better than yours.

As for *writing SMS faster* you mention, I am not that certain that there will be sufficient speed up to make it appealing for users - even in the case of "competing" against *[1-abc] [2-def] keypad*.

- Let's see... what would it take for user to print word "SMS"...

  - On your keypad:
    Select-button for S. Up-right-Select for M. Left-down-select for S.
    **5 buttons, 7 presses.**
  - On phone keypad:
    4 presses on [7-pqrs] for S. 1 press on [6-mno] for M. 4 presses on [7-pqrs] for S.
    **3 buttons, 9 presses.**
     
    Not much difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Yup you are right, perhaps it s not gonna help user too much, but still want to develop it [just to learn], please help

Comment: I see. What part of design are you having problems with - UI or sending SMS? or something else?

Comment: I cant design the UI, and it will be great if you share the code too to send a SMS :)

Comment: for UI you mentioned _simple calculator_ could you please add its screen shot to your question - so that i could figure where to start? As for SMS code code examples, you'll likely find plenty if you search the web for something like _J2ME WMA getting started_ (WMA is API to work with messaging, JSR 120 / 205)